# MavensMate proselyte's questions

Tags: ide, mavensmate

Just switching to Mavensmate after a few painful months with Eclipse. I wish I had discovered this fantastic tool earlier. I'm still struggling with some concepts though. I wonder if some of you could explain them to me.
1) eclipse has an offline mode. Can I toggle the mode in Maven?
2) when is the diff tool "compare to" available?
3) is it possible to delete files locally but keep them on the server?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) No, mavensmate does not support offline mode. It uses Tooling API to check the compilation result; it does not have local compiler.

2) Diff tool is available now. It opens when you try to save the file that was changed on the SF side or by another developer and you didn't synced the last changes to your local file.

3) Yes, you can select metadata with which you are going to work. Just go to Mavensmate -> Project -> Edit Project and select required metadata objects.

Comment: 1) You can disable compiling on the server under Mavensmate->Settings->User and set "mm_compile_on_save" to false. It's as close to off-line mode as MavensMate has.

Comment: 3) Or you can just delete the file in the sidebar by right-clicking on it and selecting "Delete" (as opposed to Mavensmate->Delete Files from Salesforce Server). Note that this method does not remove the file from your package.xml, so running MavensMate->Project->Clean Project may bring the file back to your local file system again.